# Microsoft Reporting Services Response time

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have created a report with Report Builder 3.0
I'm running it on Microsoft Reporting services 2012

When O look in the performance logs (via ExecutionLog3) I see that all 3 phases(Retrieval, Processing, Rendering) took about 2 secs. But the browser take 7+ sec to present it (and it is consistent that there is 5-10 seconds overhead), what might be the source of it?

Answer (score 0):

Could be one of two things most commonly:

1. The problem MAY BE, not sure, that your SSRS server is recycling every 12 hours and the first report of the day may be accessing the catalog on the ReportServer, getting the site up and running and then giving you a report.  Generally this is common with SSRS and sometimes may take up to a minute for the first report of the day.  Generally you can create a 'keep alive' service to poke SSRS every few hours at http:// (servername)/ReportServer which is SSRS's web service.  You can also I have read set a config setting on the SSRS server itself but that never worked for me so I gave up and created a keep alive service instead.
2. The report can be taking a long time if a developer created a lot of functions on top of the data to render it with font changes, size changes, color changes, dynamic logic.  You mentioned 'Rendering' in the time you looked up but if the report is not rendering in the browser how are you seeing rendering happen faster?

Generally it is both of these things in different situations.  Best way to check 2 is create  a super simple report with no parameters and a simple dataset that returns a black and white grid.